# How to move an arrayList of objects in the direction of another object-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on a scene2D game and want to mimic the movement of snake in game snake vs blocks.

I have a head object which moves in the direction of user's finger swipe.
While swiping,a number of objects are sequentially added below the head in an array list.When head moves,arraylist objects also moves along with it.These things I did successfully.

Now when it moves,it appears as a single object like this:

[image]

Now I want

But I want to make the movement  feels like they are different parts.
Each added object should follow the direction of the head.

Something like this:

[image]

Now I set positions like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <parts.size(); i++){
       circles.get(i).setPosition(head.getX()-head.getRadius(),
            (head.getY()-(head.getRadius()*3))-(60*i));
        }
```

I tried setting x position manually while handling touch control:

```
 private void handleSwipeInput() {
    if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown) {
        float movedir = MyInputProcessor.dist > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        float speed = 20;
        float actualSpeed = Math.abs(MyInputProcessor.dist) >= speed ? speed : Math.abs(MyInputProcessor.dist);
        if (movedir > 0) {
            head.setX(head.getX() + actualSpeed);
            for (int i = 0; i <parts.size(); i++){
            circles[i].setX(head.getX()-head.getRadius() + actualSpeed+
     (5*i));

            }
            MyInputProcessor.dist -= actualSpeed;

        } else {
            frame.setX(frame.getX() - actualSpeed);
            for (int i = 0; i <parts.size(); i++){
            circles[i].setX(head.getX()-head.getRadius() - actualSpeed-
           (5*i));

            }
            MyInputProcessor.dist += actualSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an ugly and super jerky movement. Seems that is not the perfect way.

It would be helpful if I get some suggestions and ideas for implementing this smooth movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the effect,I used **Universal Tween engine** and given different delay times incrementally for each sequential item in the array.

With tween,it looks almost smooth and fine.

```
Tween.to(circles[i], Accessor.POS_XY,delayValue[i])
                     .target(frame.getX()-frame.getRadius(),circles[i].getY())
                    .start(tweenManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Head has got a direction (vector) (Vector2 directionVector) in which it keeps moving.
Every frame position of head is changed by this vector.
In order to obtain smooth direction change:
Maximum change per frame  in  head's direction should be delta.

Where delta closer to zero is smoother movement.

So if you want to change direction of the head you do it gradually till you obtain new direction. Do it in update() method by adding delta to direction and check if new direction was obtained.

Also in update() method you should update array:
First circle in an array gets positon of the head.second circle gets position of first circle and so on.